# Find the Jacobian of the following function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

We start with a problem where we need to find u such that
$$\frac { { d }^{ 2 }u }{ dx^{ 2 } } +\lambda { e }^{ u }=0$$
with 0 < x < 1, u(0)=u(1)=0 and $\lambda$ is a known constant.

We discretize the problem by using central finite-differences. We obtain the following non-linear set of equations
$$\frac { u_{ i+1 }-2u_{ i }+u_{ i-1 } }{ h^{ 2 } } +\lambda { e }^{ u_{ i } }=0,\ i=1...n$$

where $u_i$ approximates $u(x_i)$ and $x_i$ = ih for i = 1,...,n with h = 1/(1+n). We also denote U $\in R^n$ the vector with entries $u_1$,...,$u_n$

We write the set of equations for $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ as a non-linear equation f(U) = 0 with f:$R^n \to R^n$. What is the Jacobian of f?

Comment: I don't understand, you already have the formula written above?

Comment: Yes. The formula written is what we have. @copper.hat

Comment: So you know how to write the function $f$ then. Then just compute ${\partial f(u) \over \partial u_k}$.

Comment: I don't see what is the function f that takes in the vector of $u_i$'s

Comment: $[f(u)]_i = \frac { u_{ i+1 }-2u_{ i }+u_{ i-1 } }{ h^{ 2 } } +\lambda { e }^{ u_{ i } }$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Comment: so is $\frac { \partial f }{ \partial { u }_{ k } } =\ \frac { -2 }{ h } +\lambda { e }^{ { u }_{ k } }$ or is there something I am missing?

Comment: You are missing some terms from the linear part. You can write $f(u) = {1 \over h^2}Au + \lambda \operatorname{diag}(e^{u_1},...,e^{u_n})$.

Comment: What is A in that function

Comment: Well, your equation above has $u_0$ and $u_{n+1}$ which I am guessing was unintended. But basically $A$ is tridiagonal and has $-2$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the off diagonals.

Comment: $u_0$ and $u_{n+1}$ are determined by the boundary conditions, that is $u_0$=0 and $u_{n+1}$=0 ... So your function in that case would not return an N by 1 vector...

Comment: Look, write out the equations for $i=2,...,n-1$. Then write the equation for $i=1$ with $u_0=0$ a fixed constant. Then do the same for $i=n$ and $u_{n+1} = 0$. The function maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But when you take the partials, the equations for $i=1,n$ will be slightly different than $i=2,...,n-1$. You can write it I have above or not. I think the matrix is simpler, but it is your choice.

Comment: One last question .. is the Jacobian 1 by n or n by n?

Comment: Well, the function is $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so at each point, the Jacobian will be a square matrix $Df(x):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.